# I have to specify my local Appium server URL. Where/How can I find the URL?

Tags: appium, appium-android, testcomplete, bitbar

I am trying to run an automation test using smartbear testcomplete using a local device/mobile. To be able to do this, I have to specify my local Appium server URL. Where/how can I find the URL?

See the attached screenprint.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sNZ9.png)

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You should add a few more instructions, links can bad and the answer looses its meaning, you could paste the image into your answer to improve it a bit more. Or give instructions on how to find the location where it needs to be entered.

Comment: If you run a local Appium server the host should be just localhost - `http://localhost:4723/wd/hub`

Answer (score 2):

You can enter http://localhost:4723/wd/hub to connect to your local appium server in TestComplete (see attached image).

[Connecting to local appium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtlFx.jpg)

For more info about running mobile tests w/TestComplete and Appium can be found [here](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/mobile/device-cloud/index.html).